# React Native - parameters passed to a component during navigation stay with that component when it is navigated to again later

Tags: javascript, react-native, parameters, parameter-passing, listener

As a workaround with my navigation setup, I ended up having to navigate to a child navigator before navigating to a route on that navigator (I was going from parent navigator to child navigator). When the child navigator is loaded initially, it loads `CameraScreen.js`, but I needed to get to `RentableScreen.js` which is a screen on the child navigator with `CameraScreen.js`. I used `CameraScreen.js` to get to `RentableScreen.js` from the main `App` navigator (`HomeScreen.js`). The way I did this was to use `addListener` to listen for when the page is focused on, and it gets the parameter, telling it to continue to `RentableScreen.js` and then navigates to `RentableScreen.js` - the code for this is below:

CameraScreen.js

...

```
componentDidMount() {    
    this._sub = this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'didFocus',
      () => {
        if(this.props.navigation.getParam('param', '') === 'RentTab') {
          console.log('I HEARD YOU');

          this.navigator && this.navigator.dispatch(
            NavigationActions.navigate({
              routeName: 'Rentable',
            })
          );
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

...

This all works correctly, but it seems like the parameter I pass gets "stuck to" `CameraScreen.js` because the next time I try to navigate to it (by pressing a tab on a `TabNavigator`) it acts as if I was sending it the parameter it had received before, but I am not. It seems like the parameter is being saved/held somewhere - how do I clear it? Or how do I make it so that the `addListener` doesn't pay attention when coming from the `TabNavigator`?

Answer (score 1):

This code works how I want:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._sub = this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'didFocus',
      () => {
        if(this.props.navigation.getParam('param', '') === 'RentTab') {
          this.navigator && this.navigator.dispatch(
            NavigationActions.navigate({
              routeName: 'Rentable',
            })
          );

          this.props.navigation.state.params = null; //THIS CLEARS THE STATE PARAMS HOW I WAS DESCRIBING
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Also works for this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().state.params = null; Thanks man!